# How to check login sessions to deny mutiple logins to c# winform application in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to create a stored procedure in SQL Server that when a C# Winforms application tries to login, it will check if username and password is correct.

After that, if any connections are already open (main idea is to deny multiple logins to application), it will not allow to open application on another computer.

My problem is when I run this procedure in SQL Server Management Studio with this command

```
openSession 'username', 'pass'
```

it returns what I need is

```
loginStatus = 2 or 3
```

But when I execute this command in my C# application, it returns everytime:

```
 loginStatus = 1
```

Complete SQL Server procudure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[openSession]
    @username VARCHAR(50),
    @password VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @isLoginSuccess INT;

    BEGIN
        SELECT
            @isLoginSuccess = COUNT(*)
        FROM
            Users 
        WHERE
            users.Username = @username AND Users.Pwd = @password
    END

    IF @isLoginSuccess > 0              
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS loginStatus 
        FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
        WHERE is_user_process = 1 
          AND original_login_name = @username
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 AS loginStatus
    END
END
```

In client side C# application:

```
if (stat == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login failed! Please check username or password!");
}
else if (stat == 1)
{
    // Program.isSessionOpen = true;
    // this.Close();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Application already!");
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I can see the issue happing Select 0 as LoginStatus. Instead of 0 can u return the result. Hope this one help

Comment: "select 0" is being returned when username or password is wrong.

Comment: Try to run query on SQL instead of SP and check what is the result you get if you have multiple session running for that user.